# Emulate a "tuple" data structure when the syntax for creating a tuple is predefined and cannot be altered

Tags: macros, package-writing, data-structures

Imagine I have a macro `\createcontact` that accepts three parameters. Now, instead of using these during the expansion, I would like to save them separately for later use and retrieval. The above macro is used in the following context:

```
\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}{\createcontact{Alice}{Munich}{Germany}}
\newcommand{\mysecondauthor}{\createcontact{Bob}{London}{United Kingdom}}
% and so forth
```

How do I implement `\createcontact` so that I can extract the individual parameters that have been passed to it from `\myfirstauthor`, `\mysecondauthor` etc.? How would then the code for the extraction look like? In other words, how do I need to define `\createcontact` and, say, a macro `\extractsecond` so that `\extractsecond\myfirstauthor` expands to `Munich`?

**EDIT**: Note that only the definition of `\createcontact` can be adapted, not that of `\myfirstauthor`, `\mysecondauthor` etc.. That is, the usage pattern above must remain "as is".

The reason of this exercise is that the above pattern is used in users' documents all over the place. I would like to do more complex processing of the `\createcontact` parameters than simply using them *once* in a macro. (For example, I want to use `Munich` in one context, and `Germany` in another.)

As per Peter's request, here comes a "compilable" example that has placeholders instead of the commands I'm interested in:

```
\documentclass{article}

% HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?
\newcommand{\createcontact}[3]{...}
\newcommand{\extractfirst}[1]{...}
\newcommand{\extractsecond}[1]{...}
\newcommand{\extractthird}[1]{...}
% HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?

% DO NOT CHANGE OR MOVE THIS
\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}{\createcontact{Alice}{Munich}{Germany}}
\newcommand{\mysecondauthor}{\createcontact{Bob}{London}{United Kingdom}}
% DO NOT CHANGE OR MOVE THIS

\begin{document}
  \extractfirst{\myfirstauthor} lives in \extractsecond{\myfirstauthor}
  which is located in \extractthird{\myfirstauthor};
  this may or may not be true for \extractfirst{\mysecondauthor}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think what you want is to use different definitions for `\createcontact` depending on the context.  This aim might be achievable by doing `\renewcommand{\createcontact}[3]{#2}` for instance to have `\myfirstauthor` typeset `Munich`, and replacing `#2` by `#3` would make `\myfirstauthor typeset `Germany`.  Please clarify when you want each behaviour, and what should trigger the change in behaviour.

Comment: Can the `\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}` be moved to the preamble?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, it could. I have edited accordingly. But it cannot come before the definitions of `\create...` and `\extract...`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Thank you for the hint, I think I can implement it in the way you suggested: (Re)define `\createcontact` only in the `\extract...` macros. Do you want to convert this to an answer?

Comment: Is the content between the two `% DO NOT CHANGE THIS` coming from a separate file?  It would be easier to add code after the definitions of `\myfirstauthor` and before `\begin{document}`, but can work around this if really needed. Also, is it ok to change `\extractfirst{\myfirstauthor}` to `\extractfirst{myfirstauthor}` (slash removed)?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes to both. Do you intend to use an `\AtBeginDocument` command? Why not simply (as @BrunoLeFloch suggested) `\newcommand{\extractfirst}[#1]{\newcommand{\createcontact}[3]{##1}#1}` (not sure about syntax)?

Comment: Yes I was going to use `\AtBeginDocument` to redefine the commands, if I can't simply add them after the defintions of `myfirstauthor`. I don't see how changing `\extractfirst` will help, you need to redefine the `\createcontact` depending on if `\myfirstauthor` is used or `\mysecondauthor` is used.

Comment: @PeterGrill: The trick is to redefine `\createcontact` *inside* the `\extract...` commands; see my answer. I'm still open to better/more elegant/... solutions :-)

Comment: @user946850: Hmmm.. That too seems to work, and seems much simpler that my solution, although I find is strange since you are using `\renewcommand{\createcontact}[3]`, but not providing three parameters.

Comment: `\createcontact` _expects_ three parameter, but each definition uses only one of them; the others are silently discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lambda lists:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lambda} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lambda-lists
%
\def\createcontact#1#2#3{\Listize[#1,#2,#3]}
\let\extractfirst\Head
\def\extractsecond#1{\extractfirst{\Tail{#1}}}
\def\extractthird#1{\extractsecond{\Tail{#1}}}
%
\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}{\createcontact{Alice}{Munich}{Germany}}
\newcommand{\mysecondauthor}{\createcontact{Bob}{London}{United Kingdom}}
%
\begin{document}
  \extractfirst{\myfirstauthor} lives in \extractsecond{\myfirstauthor}
  which is located in \extractthird{\myfirstauthor};
  (or \Head{\Tail{\Tail{\myfirstauthor}}},
  or \Head{\Reverse{\myfirstauthor}})
  this may or may not be true for \extractfirst{\mysecondauthor}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's nice code using one of the less widely known packages. Is it possible to code an accessor that accepts a number, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48938/emulate-a-tuple-data-structure-when-you-are-free-to-choose-the-syntax?

Comment: @user946850: I was actually thinking about that; something like a `\nth` macro. But then I realized all assignments happen in TeX's stomach (functional bell ringing?). So then I thought how to do Church numerals in TeX's mouth, and realized you could [use e-TeX extensions for the number](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92jackowski.pdf). Then all that is left is to build the list so, that it includes an index. I haven't done any of this, I'm merely thinking out loud here.

Answer (score 8):

### Basic Solution:

Without more details it is difficult to know if something as simple as this will work for you:  You call `\myfirstauthor{Kenobi}{General}{1138}`, and then to access each member you simply refer to `\myfirstauthorName`, `\myfirstauthorRank`, and `\myfirstauthorSerialNum`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}[3]{%
    \newcommand{\myfirstauthorName}{#1}%
    \newcommand{\myfirstauthorRank}{#2}%
    \newcommand{\myfirstauthorSerialNum}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\myfirstauthor{Kenobi}{General}{1138}

The details of the first author are:

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Name: & \myfirstauthorName\\
Rank: & \myfirstauthorRank\\
Serial Number: & \myfirstauthorSerialNum
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

### Alternate Solution:

Instead of creating a list of separate macors `\myfirstauthor`, `\mysecondauthor`, etc you could specify the differentiation between them as the first parameter to the `\myauthor` macro.  This yields a more flexible solution as you can create the macros on the fly.  So with this solution yo can use `\myauthor[first]{Kenobi}{General}{1138}` (or leave out the `first` as that is the default), but others can simply be defined by `\myauthor[second]{Dooku}{Count}{66}`, and accessed as in the above case to yield:

[image]

To create another one you just use `\myauthor[third]{}{}{}`, etc...

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myauthor}[4][first]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname my#1authorName\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname my#1authorRank\endcsname{#3}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname my#1authorSerialNum\endcsname{#4}%
}

\begin{document}
\myauthor{Kenobi}{General}{1138}
\myauthor[second]{Dooku}{Count}{66}

The details of the first two authors are:

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rll}
Name: & \myfirstauthorName & \mysecondauthorName\\
Rank: & \myfirstauthorRank & \mysecondauthorRank\\
Serial Number: & \myfirstauthorSerialNum & \mysecondauthorSerialNum
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

### Solution Based on given MWE:

With the revised restrictions, you can use `\AtBeginDocument` to change the definition of
`\createcontact` based on if `\myfirstauthor` or `\mysecondauthor` is called:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?
\newcommand{\createcontact}[3]{}
\newcommand{\extractfirst}[1]{\csname #1Name\endcsname}
\newcommand{\extractsecond}[1]{\csname #1City\endcsname}
\newcommand{\extractthird}[1]{\csname #1Country\endcsname}

\newcommand{\myfirstauthorName}{}%
\newcommand{\myfirstauthorCity}{}%
\newcommand{\myfirstauthorCountry}{}%
\newcommand{\CreateFirstContact}[3]{%
    \renewcommand{\myfirstauthorName}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\myfirstauthorCity}{#2}%
    \renewcommand{\myfirstauthorCountry}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\mysecondauthorName}{}%
\newcommand{\mysecondauthorCity}{}%
\newcommand{\mysecondauthorCountry}{}%
\newcommand{\CreateSecondContact}[3]{%
    \renewcommand{\mysecondauthorName}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\mysecondauthorCity}{#2}%
    \renewcommand{\mysecondauthorCountry}{#3}%
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\OldFirstAuthor\myfirstauthor
    \let\OldSecondAuthor\mysecondauthor
    \renewcommand{\myfirstauthor}{\let\createcontact\CreateFirstContact\OldFirstAuthor}
    \renewcommand{\mysecondauthor}{\let\createcontact\CreateSecondContact\OldSecondAuthor}
    \myfirstauthor
    \mysecondauthor
}
% HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?

% DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}{\createcontact{Alice}{Munich}{Germany}}
\newcommand{\mysecondauthor}{\createcontact{Bob}{London}{United Kingdom}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
  \extractfirst{myfirstauthor} lives in \extractsecond{myfirstauthor}
  which is located in \extractthird{myfirstauthor};
  this may or may not be true for \extractfirst{mysecondauthor}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but this is not what I meant. The "API" is given -- I can only alter the definition of `\createcontact`, but I cannot do anything about how `\myfirstauthor`, `\mysecondauthor` etc. are defined.

Comment: @user946850: Can you please compose a _compilable_ example that illustrates exactly what you want.  Commands can be redefined and changed. But without more details it is is difficult to guess what would work for you.

Comment: I cannot produce a compilable example because I don't know how to define the commands I need in the first place. I have edited the question, and I hope it is somewhat clearer now.

Comment: @user946850: Sorry it is _not_ clear. Can you mock up a compilable example. I know it is obvious to you, but won't be to others who are not dealing exactly with your problem.

Comment: @user946850: Pretend the commands exist, and show me how you want to access them and tell me what the expected output should be. For example how do you want to access `Munich`?  You can comment that portion out it out to make it compilable.

Comment: Thank you. This is nice because it avoids repeated expansion of the full `\createcontact` macro (as opposed to my solution). I wonder if it's possible to get rid of the code-_almost_-duplication?

Comment: @user946850:Yeah you could loop that using `\csname ... \edcsname` as well.  Also I did not know if if you need to be able to use `\myfirstauthor` more than once.

Answer (score 3):

With credit to Bruno Le Floch for the idea, here is what I would consider "working for me":

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% ONE POSSIBLE SOLUTION
\newcommand{\createcontact}[3]{}
\newcommand{\extractfirst}[1]{\renewcommand{\createcontact}[3]{##1}#1}
\newcommand{\extractsecond}[1]{\renewcommand{\createcontact}[3]{##2}#1}
\newcommand{\extractthird}[1]{\renewcommand{\createcontact}[3]{##3}#1}
% ONE POSSIBLE SOLUTION

% DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\newcommand{\myfirstauthor}{\createcontact{Alice}{Munich}{Germany}}
\newcommand{\mysecondauthor}{\createcontact{Bob}{London}{United Kingdom}}
% DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\begin{document}

  \extractfirst{\myfirstauthor} lives in \extractsecond{\myfirstauthor}
  which is located in \extractthird{\myfirstauthor};
  this may or may not true for \extractfirst{\mysecondauthor}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]