# How do I read data from one cell of a table and print its content in text?

Tags: formatting, external-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting complex table from CSV using datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17618/formatting-complex-table-from-csv-using-datatool)

I have a list of hundred names with an associated ID number, name, contact info, and more...

Is it possible, knowing the associated ID number, to just print a fixed format. By example, I want to type

```
\command{10}
```

So it prints `"Text, text <i>name</i>, more text, blah for: <i>contact info</i> blah blah"`

Is that possible?
I was thinking to add the data manually in a `.txt` document or an Excel file type. (if there's another possibility, I'm willing to try it).

Comment: I was reading from this
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48938/emulate-a-tuple-data-structure-when-you-are-free-to-choose-the-syntax
Which seems to let me make a "database", but how could I combine it with some defined text structure so it automatically reads the database, replaces the data where necessary a prints a line of text with the correct names and info already?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to keep the data in a CSV file and then use the `datatool` package to manipulate it.  See [Formatting complex table from CSV using datatool](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17618/2693) for an example.

Comment: Here is a very similar problem and a solution with LuaLaTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41499/10570. Maybe it could be an approach for you.