# Use TeX macros to store multiple data

Tags: macros, tex-core, database

I'm trying to use TeX macros to store multiple data such as website url/name. Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Google{{http://www.google.com}{Google Search}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\WebSiteName[1]{\@WebSiteName\expandafter#1}
\newcommand*\WebSiteUrl[1]{\@WebSiteUrl\expandafter#1}
\newcommand*\@WebSiteName[2]{#2}
\newcommand*\@WebSiteUrl[2]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Name : \WebSiteName\Google \par
  Url  : \WebSiteUrl\Google

\end{document}
```

On this example, `\WebSiteName\Google` should write "Google Search" and `\WebSiteUrl\Google` should write "http://www.google.com".

But the problem is that `\WebSiteName\Google` writes http://www.google.comGoogle Search". I try to use `\expandafter` to combine two arguments in only one. Maybe that's the wrong method.

Comment: Related, maybe a dupe: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48938/8057 (Perhaps at another level of abstraction...)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're misplacing `\expandafter`: it must go *before* `\@WebSiteName` and `\@WebSiteUrl`. But it turns out that the two auxiliary macros are already in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WebSiteName}{\expandafter\@secondoftwo}
\newcommand{\WebSiteUrl}{\expandafter\@firstoftwo}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\NewSite}[3]{\newcommand#1{{#2}{#3}}}

\NewSite{\Google}{http://www.google.com}{Google Search}
```

When `\WebSiteName\Google` is found, it becomes

```
\expandafter\@secondoftwo\Google
```

and then `\Google` is expanded, giving

```
\@secondoftwo{http://www.google.com}{Google Search}
```

and, finally

```
Google Search
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks egreg.

Finally, after a little search, i used a different approch using the package [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool).

File: websites.csv

```
id,     url,                   name
Google, http://www.google.com, Google Search
```

File: document.tex

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{datatool}

% set "," as separator between each entry
% "," is the default
% to use <tab> as separator, use \DTLsettabseparator
\DTLsetseparator{,}

% loads the database
\DTLloaddb{websites}{websites.csv}

\newcommand*\WebSiteName[1]{%
  \DTLgetvalueforkey{\temp}{name}{websites}{id}{#1}%
  \temp}

\newcommand*\WebSiteUrl[1]{%
  \DTLgetvalueforkey{\temp}{url}{websites}{id}{#1}%
  \temp}

\newcommand*\WebSite[1]{%
  \WebSiteName{#1}~\WebSiteUrl{#1}}

\begin{document}

  % show database
  \DTLdisplaydb{websites}

  \WebSiteName{Google}
  \WebSiteUrl{Google}
  \WebSite{Google}

\end{document}
```